# Is ThreadID consistent when shuffling Haskell threads around OS threads?

Tags: haskell, concurrency

In Haskell forkIO creates an unbound (Haskell) thread, and forkOS creates a bound (native) thread. The answer to a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443824/how-does-hopengl-behave-with-regards-to-other-threads-and-tchans-in-haskell) that I had mentioned that Haskell threads are not guaranteed to stay on the same OS thread, which seems to be supported by the documentation for the [Control.Concurrent](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.5.1.0/doc/html/Control-Concurrent.html) module. My question is, if a running Haskell thread gets swapped to another OS thread, will its ThreadID remain the same?

Comment: forkOS doesn't create a new OS thread, it binds that lightweight thread to only be run on a single OS thread. this is important for things like OpenGL which use thread specific data behind the scenes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

> A `ThreadId` is an abstract type representing a handle to a thread.

This is how you send asynchronous signals to specific threads: with the `ThreadId`.  It does not matter which OS thread is involved, and it is often quite likely that the targeted thread is not bound to any OS thread at all (e.g., it is sleeping).

The existence of "OS threads" is somewhat an implementation detail, although you'll need to manage them if you use the FFI with certain libraries.  Otherwise, you can mostly ignore OS threads in your code.